# GNU Make hangs on pipe write

Tags: linux, makefile, pipe, gnu-make

Occasionally GNU Make hangs, forever. The environment is a 64 logical core x86-64 Ubuntu 16.04 Linux 4.4 machine. (It has also happened in previous Linux versions.)

The makefile is using `-j65 -l69`. No rules use the `+` jobserver inheritance.

```
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(shell expr $$(nproc) + 1) -l$(shell expr $$(nproc) + 5)
```

The process is

```
$ ps aux | grep make
myuser  100694  0.0  0.0  86268 80016 ?        S    15:14   0:28 make
```

The process hangs on writing `"+"` to a pipe.

```
$ strace -s 99 -ffp 100694
strace: Process 100694 attached
write(4, "+", 1
$ sudo cat /proc/100694/stack
[<ffffffff81216080>] pipe_wait+0x70/0xc0
[<ffffffff81216207>] pipe_write+0xc7/0x420
[<ffffffff8120d0bb>] new_sync_write+0x9b/0xe0
[<ffffffff8120d126>] __vfs_write+0x26/0x40
[<ffffffff8120daa9>] vfs_write+0xa9/0x1a0
[<ffffffff8120e765>] SyS_write+0x55/0xc0
[<ffffffff81816d72>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x71
[<ffffffffffffffff>] 0xffffffffffffffff
```

I recognize this behavior as GNU Make's [jobserver](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/jobserver-implementation/) indicating there is available capacity.

As expected, the process has the pipe open for reading and writing.

```
$ ls /proc/100694/fd
0  1  10  11  12  13  14  15  2  3  4  6  7  8  9
$ stat /proc/100694/fd/4
File: '/proc/100694/fd/4' -> 'pipe:[1617033]'
$ lsof | grep 1617033
make      100694           myuser    3r     FIFO               0,10      0t0    1617033 pipe
make      100694           myuser    4w     FIFO               0,10      0t0    1617033 pipe
```

1. To my understanding, for a pipe write to hang, the pipe must have reached its 4048 byte capacity. Correct?
2. Can I see the size or contents of this pipe?
3. Are there any tools I can use to debug this situation futher?

Comment: I presume you've reduced this to a minimal complete example. Is there some reason you aren't showing it to us?

Comment: @Beta, unfortunately I have not. As it is, the issue is very intermittent, making it hard to test whether a reduced example still has the necessary characteristics. Moreover, I suspect this to be highly system dependent.

Comment: What version of GNU make are you using?

Comment: @MadScientist, 4.1 -- the version available in Ubuntu 16.04 (and 17.04) repos. It may have also happened with Ubuntu 14.04's 3.81; I can't remember.

Comment: I've never seen an issue where make is hung on a write operation and I can't imagine how that could happen.  However there have been a few different issues related to hangs during jobserver for other reasons.  The best thing to do is, if possible, get the latest Git sources and build them (unfortunately you'll need to install a number of other packages such as autoconf, automake, autopoint, gettext, makeinfo, etc.) and see if the issue persists.  You can try with GNU make 4.2.1 (the latest release) but there are fixes newer than that as well.

Comment: @MadScientist, I'm at a loss too. Thanks for taking a look. I have built make from source (previously using the Debian source package). I might try it.